# Magento 1.x - plugin Rest API extension?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, module, plugin

I am new in Magento environment and wanted to ask you folks, if you can help me with this problem. I have a client that doesn't allow me to access his magento sourcecode and alter it. The only way for them is to develop by me a plugin/module for Magento, to enable cart and checkout for mobile users as Rest API. I wanted to ask you is this possible and could you please point me out some tutorials for that task?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom API for magento as a plugin.

Look at this for reference.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/create_your_own_api.html

Hope this will help you.